# How can I import shapefile in python?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, shapefile

How can I import a shapefile in python?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QFileDialog
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources_rc
# Import the code for the dialog
from Import_tool_dialog import ImporttoolDialog
from functools import partial as pto
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import showinfo, showwarning, showerror
from xlrd import open_workbook
import os
import shutil
import time
import psycopg2
import shapefile as shp
```

Here I am getting error :

```
ImportError: No module named shapefile.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the module your looking for is pyshp.
if it isn't installed, open your osgeo shell and enter

> easy_install pyshp

Comment: i follow your process but still it give me error. "invalid syntax." and i will check online for solution and close the program

Comment: thank @Juls  in my osgeo shell : 
c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\ Programs\OSGeo4w>easy_install pyshp
and also try : 
c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\ Programs\OSGeo4w>python easy_install pyshp
but still getting error invalid syntax

Comment: Edit : maybe a path problem, your easy_install worked? Try following this https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/ExternalPythonPackages

Answer (score 1):

[Note that easy_install is run from the command line, not the python console.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624492/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-syntax-easy-install-error). So from a terminal window in linux, cmd in Windows etc.

I'm sure that in the past I've just downloaded the shapefile.py to the project source folder.

This library is pure python, consists of one .py file and has no external dependencies, so try that if you can't get easy_install to work from the command line.